# Eslint config file from codacy

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint, software-quality, codacy

I'm using codacy to monitor code quality, but it would be nice to see what codacy will catch before a push. I see that it uses eslint and several other tools to decide what to catch. Is there a way to generate a .eslintrc config file from codacy? That way I can use this config in Webstorm and make any necessary changes before pushing any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible at this moment to generate a .eslintrc or JHint/JSLint file from Codacy itself. You can import those config files in Codacy but not export them.

Answer (score 4):

2 years later Codacy still doesn't provide an export tool. So the best approach seems to be mimic Codacy configuration on ESLint demo (https://eslint.org/demo/) then click "Download .eslintrc.json file with this configuration" at the bottom of the page. You will need to check/uncheck rules again, but at least you will get a configuration file for future use.